# How do I force the system to look for new sound devices?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, sound

I have a small flat screen TV (Toshiba) that I often connect via HDMI to my laptop (an HP Pavilion dv4) and use as a computer monitor. When I do this, I prefer to use the TV's speakers, particularly when I'm watching video, because the sound quality is much better.

However, when I connect the HDMI cable after turning on my computer (rather than having it plugged in before booting up), Sound Settings does not list the TV as an output device, and I am forced to reboot.

I was curious if there is an easier solution to this, perhaps a CLI command to check for new sound outputs. Does anyone know of something like this or have another solution?

To clarify, I believe this is a software problem. The HDMI always works, and I can switch my desktop over to the TV at any time. The issue is that, if the HDMI wasn't connected during start up, the TV will not appear as an output option in the Sound Settings GUI. So, unless I'm mistaken, my question is not HDMI specific, but rather a general usage question about manipulating sound settings from the command line.

Output of 'cat /proc/asound/cards':

```
0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xda500000 irq 48
```

Update:
Here's some of the outputs requested. Sorry for the delay.

Output of 'lsmod' (After booting up the computer, connecting the HDMI, and successfully setting the HDMI-connected screen as the sole monitor. However, HDMI is not listed as an option in the Sound Settings GUI):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
michael_mic            12612  0 
arc4                   12529  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23200  0 
vboxnetadp             13382  0 
vboxnetflt             23441  0 
vboxdrv               287082  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
bnep                   18281  2 
parport_pc             32866  0 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
bluetooth             180104  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70795  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
i915                  473298  2 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17390  0 
ir_lirc_codec          12859  0 
lirc_dev               19204  1 ir_lirc_codec
wl                   2568210  0 
uvcvideo               72627  0 
ir_mce_kbd_decoder     12777  0 
snd                    78855  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
ir_sony_decoder        12510  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
soundcore              15091  1 snd
ir_jvc_decoder         12507  0 
psmouse                97443  0 
ir_rc6_decoder         12507  0 
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lib80211               14381  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
hp_wmi                 18092  0 
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
serio_raw              13211  0 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
hp_accel               25976  0 
ir_rc5_decoder         12507  0 
drm                   241921  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
jmb38x_ms              17646  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
wmi                    19256  1 hp_wmi
memstick               16569  1 jmb38x_ms
lis3lv02d              19876  1 hp_accel
ir_nec_decoder         12507  0 
video                  19596  1 i915
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
rc_rc6_mce             12502  0 
coretemp               13525  0 
ene_ir                 18457  0 
rc_core                26412  10 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,ene_ir
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
sdhci_pci              18826  0 
sdhci                  33205  1 sdhci_pci
r8169                  62099  0
```

Output of 'lsmod' (After only restarting the computer. HDMI Output is now appears in Sound Settings):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23200  0 
vboxnetadp             13382  0 
vboxnetflt             23441  0 
vboxdrv               287082  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70795  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
bluetooth             180104  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               72627  0 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17390  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
wl                   2568210  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
joydev                 17693  0 
ir_lirc_codec          12859  0 
lirc_dev               19204  1 ir_lirc_codec
snd                    78855  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
ir_mce_kbd_decoder     12777  0 
i915                  473298  2 
soundcore              15091  1 snd
ir_sony_decoder        12510  0 
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
lib80211               14381  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
psmouse                97443  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
hp_wmi                 18092  0 
ir_jvc_decoder         12507  0 
drm                   241921  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
jmb38x_ms              17646  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
memstick               16569  1 jmb38x_ms
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
ir_rc6_decoder         12507  0 
ir_rc5_decoder         12507  0 
ir_nec_decoder         12507  0 
wmi                    19256  1 hp_wmi
rc_rc6_mce             12502  0 
ene_ir                 18457  0 
rc_core                26412  10 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,ene_ir
hp_accel               25976  0 
lis3lv02d              19876  1 hp_accel
video                  19596  1 i915
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
coretemp               13525  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
r8169                  62099  0 
sdhci_pci              18826  0 
sdhci                  33205  1 sdhci_pci
```

Comment: This could be a device specific problem, maybe retitle / edit your question to "How do I get HDMI out working on a ..." then whatever your laptop is.

Comment: Also if you could add some hardware information that would help, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I don't think I was perfectly clear in my first post. Does this make sense? Is there any hardware information that you would still like?

Comment: Add the results of `cat /proc/asound/cards` to your question, that should let us know what kind of audio chipset it is.

Comment: I don't know if this would help, but if the problem is module related, it would help if you saved the output of `lsmod` both before and after rebooting the computer. Perhaps if you boot the computer with the HDMI plugged, the kernel loads a vital module